# How to set system Short Date to ISO format "yyyy-MM-dd" in High Sierra?

Tags: high-sierra, time

When setting the preferences for the short date string, 
the Day of Month does not include the trailing 0. How can I change this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I found the answer myself (at least I have what I want):

My problem:
[image: day of month missing trailing zero]

System Preferences... > Language & Region > Advanced... > Dates

What I expected was the option to open the Day of Month drop down and select an option with a trailing zero, just as the digit Month allows:

[image: Month digit drop down shows with and without trailing zero]

But I don't see that:

[image: trailing zero missing from Day of Month]

So when my Googling came up empty, I coincidentally copied the contents of the Short field

[image: short date field]

into a text editor and this is what I found:

[image: y-MM-d]

So I got the bright idea of pasting "yyyy-MM-dd" into the Short date field and seeing what happens. Sure enough, worked like a charm:

[image: trailing zero in day of month]

This also worked with getting the trailing zeros in Excel on the year:

Before:

[image: Awful y-MM-d date format in Mac Excel 2011]

After:

[image: ISO "yyyy-MM-dd" date format in Mac Excel 2011]

Answer (score 1):

Use/copy the Swedish locale for date and time. It follows the ISO-standard.